# Using offset fetch next only on condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

What would the best way be of using offset next based on a condition.

Having something like this in mind but am getting compilation error.

```
        declare @Condition bit

        select
        canvas.CanvasName,
        c.CompanyID,
        c.CompanyName
        from JobCanvas_B2B canvas
        inner join JobActivity act on act.CanvasId = canvas.CanvasId
        inner join [Person_5.4] p on p.JobCanvasId = canvas.CanvasId
        inner join Person pers on pers.PersonId = p.PersonId
        inner join Company c on c.CompanyID = pers.CompanyId
        where act.NextDateD  between @StartDate and @EndDate

         order by  act.InteractionDateD  desc

         if(@Condition = 1)
         begin
            offset @SkipRows rows 
            fetch next @PageSize rows only
         end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can pick a sensible default upper limit for number of rows to return, just use some `CASE` expressions:

```
    declare @Condition bit

    select
    canvas.CanvasName,
    c.CompanyID,
    c.CompanyName
    from JobCanvas_B2B canvas
    inner join JobActivity act on act.CanvasId = canvas.CanvasId
    inner join [Person_5.4] p on p.JobCanvasId = canvas.CanvasId
    inner join Person pers on pers.PersonId = p.PersonId
    inner join Company c on c.CompanyID = pers.CompanyId
    where act.NextDateD  between @StartDate and @EndDate
    order by  act.InteractionDateD  desc

    offset CASE WHEN @Condition = 1 THEN @SkipRows ELSE 0 END rows 
    fetch next CASE WHEN @Condition = 1 THEN @PageSize ELSE 1000000 END rows only
```

You can't "stop" in the middle of defining a query and start writing control flow statements (like `IF`) to decide how a part of your query should be structured.

Comment: That;s perfect, thank you. Tried the case when but missed the 'else' stupidly.